# how can i run iphone 2.0 in iphone 3.2 sdk

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone.i am installing the iphone sdk 3.2 with xcode 3.2.when i run the some pre defined examples it shows an error there is no sdk named iphone2.0.If i need to install iphone sdk 2.0 how can i install with out overriding the existing sdk means i need both sdk 2.0 and sdk 3.0. how can i done this pls help me.thank  u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You *always* build/compile against the latest SDK. in your case that's 3.2. Just set your deployment target to 2.0 and you will run those devices - that is if you don't rely on features of later versions.

Just as a not: if you plan to submit you app to the AppStore, you must use 4.x and target 3.x minimum.

Answer (score 0):

change the base SDK instead by scrolling down the list on the left in XCode and expand "Targets". Click on the name of the app inside this and press the blue info button at the top in the middle.

Make sure you have the "Build" tab selected and that you choose "All configurations" in the configuration drop down.

Then change the base SDK to 3.2. Its about the 3rd option down I think.

Hope that helps.